# What is the difference between repositories and table objects in cakephp v3.x?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have been using Cakephp ver2.x and just started migrating to Cakephp v3.x. When I tried using the new ORM, I am baffled by basic concepts like repositories and table objects. What is the difference between repositories and table objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A repository can be anything while a table, as the name states, is just a table.

http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html

> Represents a single database table.
>
> Exposes methods for retrieving data out of it, and manages the associations this table has to other tables. Multiple instances of this class can be created for the same database table with different aliases, this allows you to address your database structure in a richer and more expressive way.

http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Datasource.RepositoryInterface.html

> Describes the methods that any class representing a data storage should comply with.

A data storage can be any kind of storage system, even one that doesn't know tables like a graph DB or document based system.

It is always simple to just check the API documentation and code for this kind of questions. The code is pretty well documented. Also the way this works becomes obvious then:

```
class Table implements RepositoryInterface, EventListenerInterface
```

Table implements the interface defined by RepositoryInterface.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. Please check my understanding. When I retrieve data from a single table, I use a table. When I retrieve data from multiple tables, I use a repository. Is this correct?

Comment: No, a table is a single table. A repository is an interface to anything.  That you ask this indicates that you haven't read the manual. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html but I recommend you to start with the tutorials http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html.

Comment: No, its more like Fruits and Food. You can eat "Fruits" (Models), but you could also eat any "Food" (Repositories), which logically can be anything. So Fruits are a subset of Food, Models a subset of Repositories. And a Table is just a single type of Fruit, e.g. an Apple, thus "apples" table. Oh, and it returns an Apple (Entity), a single entity of that sort of fruit.

Comment: @burzum: You're right. I thought my background in cakephp v2.x would be enough. I didn't expect learning curve to v3.x would be so steep.